# How to generate a csv with a double pipe delimiter?

Tags: dataweave, mulesoft, mule4

I want to generate a CSV output based on "||" as separator. I tried concatenation and other different approaches but I'm not able to achieve the desired output.

Input payload:

```
[
    {

        "details": "products' details; LED; 10-34V; 90 CRI; 300j-400h; 708-150 lm; 6 in.AVAIL",
        "Id": "AgXS31456",
        "age": "25"
    }
]
```

Used script:

```
%dw 2.0
output application/csv  header=false, separator="|"

---
payload map ((item) -> {
    "field_1": item.Id ,
    "field_2": item.details,
    "field_3": item.age
    
})
```

Expected output:

```
AgXS31456||products' details; LED; 10-34V; 90 CRI; 300j-400h; 708-150 lm; 6 in.AVAIL||25
```

Not sure if there another way to twist the script in order to get the delimiter separator as expected.

Comment: Can you update the title to say "Multi character delimiter". This looks like it can be a common problem and correct title can help other landing on this question

Answer (score 2):

The separator writer property of the DataWeave CSV format only uses a single character as separator. If you try to have a multicharacter separator it only takes the first one. To achieve what you want we'll need to do a hack and concatenate or join each field into a single string field. The field name is not relevant since you are not printing headers.

```js
%dw 2.0
output application/csv  header=false
---
payload map ((item) -> {
    "field_1": [item.Id , item.details, item.age] joinBy "||"
})
```

Output:

```csv
AgXS31456||products' details; LED; 10-34V; 90 CRI; 300j-400h; 708-150 lm; 6 in.AVAIL||25
```

Comment: @alead  awesome. that has resolved the issue. Thanks